# c# ApiController to hook request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a C# application which will just hook the requests and log to a file.

Basically, App ABC is talking to App XYZ, I need to create App PQR which will receive all Rest requests made by ABC and redirect them (no altering) to XYZ. And then respond back whatever XYZ Returns but also log it to a local file.

I have an empty C# MVC Application with MapHttpAttributeRoutes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Test",
                routeTemplate: "test",
                defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Create" });
```

Also, a controller with:

```
public class RedirectController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ..... Create()
        {
            .........................
        }
    }
```

How to redirect and return the response ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Comment: @Stefan ... I actually wanna do the same via controller. I am too new to C#. Wondering how can I get the exact HTTPRequest object in controller..... Any idea ?

Comment: Ah, in that case: you need to replicate the request. Simplest way to do so (from experience point of view) is start a new one with a HttpClient. Make sure to copy the headers, httpmethod and query string to the new request. I might be able to provide an example later today. (or someone else will answer your question)